# How to disable checksum offloading in macOS Big Sur 11.4?

Tags: networking, macos, macos-bigsur

After updating my macOS to macOS Big Sur 11.4, packets captured between my host machine and VM on my host machine shows the wrong checksum for packets at IP and TCP layer. I have captured packets inside the VM and there is no checksum error.

Thinks I tried:

1. `sysctl -w net.link.ether.inet.apple_hwcksum_rx=0` and `sysctl -w net.link.ether.inet.apple_hwcksum_tx=0`. I got the error `sysctl: unknown oid 'net.link.ether.inet.apple_hwcksum_rx'`. I checked, options available for net.link.ether.inet are

```
~: sysctl -w net.link.ether.inet.
arp_llreach_base         maxhold                  send_conflicting_probes
arp_unicast_lim          maxhold_total            sendllconflict
host_down_time           maxtries                 stats
keep_announcements       probe_intvl              useloopback
log_arp_warnings         proxyall                 verbose
max_age                  prune_intvl
```

2.`sudo ifconfig bridge100 -rxcsum -txcsum` gives `ifconfig: -rxcsum: Operation not supported on socket`.

Information about the interface bridge100:

```
bridge100: flags=8a63<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,ALLMULTI,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 index 18
    eflags=41808000<ROUTER4,CL2K,ECN_ENABLE,FASTLN_ON>
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM> <------------------I can see rxcsum here, still operation is not allowed
    ether 8a:e9:fe:55:3e:64
    inet 192.168.73.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.73.255
    inet6 fe80::1874:f039:53ce:72b7%bridge100 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x12
    inet6 fd15:4ba5:5a2b:1002:cf6:8ccd:2af9:aa84 prefixlen 64 deprecated autoconf secured
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x0
    member: en10 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 17 priority 0 path cost 0
            hostfilter 0 hw: 0:0:0:0:0:0 ip: 0.0.0.0
    member: en11 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 19 priority 0 path cost 0
            hostfilter 0 hw: 0:0:0:0:0:0 ip: 0.0.0.0
    member: en12 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 22 priority 0 path cost 0
            hostfilter 0 hw: 0:0:0:0:0:0 ip: 0.0.0.0
    Address cache:
        0:c:29:7:ba:63 Vlan1 en11 1093 flags=0<>
        0:c:29:7:ba:59 Vlan1 en12 1190 flags=0<>
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
    state availability: 0 (true)
    desc: com.apple.NetworkSharing
    qosmarking enabled: yes mode: none
    low power mode: disabled
    multi layer packet logging (mpklog): disabled
    routermode4: enabled
    routermode6: enabled
```

VM is hosted on VMware fusion 12.0

Comment: Did you try `net.link.generic.system.hwcksum_rx` and `_tx`?

Comment: @Spiff Thank you! That did the trick.

Comment: ```sudo sysctl net.link.generic.system.hwcksum_tx=0``` and ```sudo sysctl net.link.generic.system.hwcksum_rx=0``` did the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Spiff suggested I tried `sudo sysctl net.link.generic.system.hwcksum_tx=0` and `sudo sysctl net.link.generic.system.hwcksum_rx=0`, and it did the job.